# Finite Rank Commutators

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, open-problems

My former student Detelin Dosev and I are interested in classifying the commutators in $L(X)$, the bounded linear operators on the Banach space $X$ (see our joint paper on my home page or the ArXiv and the references therein, and recall that $T$ is a commutator means that there are $A$ and $B$ in $L(X)$ so that $T=AB-BA$).

If $T$ is a finite rank operator in $L(X)$ with zero trace then it is classical that $T$ is a commutator. The converse is obviously true when $X$ is finite dimensional.

Conjecture. There is an infinite dimensional Banach space $X$ such that all finite rank commutators in $L(X)$ have zero trace.

If true, this conjecture is very hard to prove, but maybe it is known to be false?

We are also interested in conditions on $X$ that guarantee that all finite rank operators in $L(X)$ are commutators.  If $X$ is isomorphic (meaning linearly homeomorphic) to its closed subspaces of codimension one, then rank one projections in $L(X)$ are commutators and hence every finite rank operator in $L(X)$ is the sum of two commutators, but we do not know whether every finite rank operator in $L(X)$ is a commutator. If also $X$ contains a complemented subspace isomorphic to $X \oplus X$, then every diagonalizable finite rank operator in $L(X)$ is a commutator, but we still don't know whether all finite rank operators in $L(X)$ are commutators.  Are we missing something easy?

A Banach space $X$ is said to have a Pelczynski decomposition provided $X$ is isomorphic to $(X \oplus X \oplus X  \oplus ...)_p$ for some $1 \le p \le \infty$ or $p = 0$.  A general result is that if $X$ admits a Pelczynski decomposition, then every compact operator on $X$ is a commutator, so standard spaces do not give examples of finite rank non commutators.

Comment: Is there a simple example of a finite rank commutator without 0 trace?

Comment: Sorry, I should have just said nonzero trace; obviously the trace exists.

Comment: On any Banach space that has a Pelczynski decomposition, all finite rank operators are commutators.  Of course, they cannot be commutators of finite rank operators, but on a Hilbert space they are commutators of compact operators by a result of Joel Anderson. (The major open question on Hilbert spaces is whether every compact operator is a commutator of compact operators.  Actually, this is open for every separable infinite dimensional Banach space!)

Comment: Perhaps I should say why I make the conjecture.  A well known problem is whether there is an infinite dimensional Banach space $X$ s.t. every bounded linear operator on $X$ is a multiple of the identity plus a nuclear operator.  On such a space every finite rank commutator would have zero trace.  

Comment: With respect to that well known problem, what's the weakest condition you can put in place of "nuclear" such that there is currently known to be such a space?

Comment: I assume you mean strongest condition, yes, Mark?  It is "uniformly approximable by finite rank operators" (since the Argyros-Haydon example, being an isomorphic pre-dual of $\ell_1$, has the approximation property). 

Comment: The problem seems to me to be very difficult, though it is  certainly true that both you and Detelin Dosev have developed much more intuition on this than myself. My comment is just a question: do you think that the spaces contructed by Gilles Pisier in Acta Math. (1983) could be related? 

Comment: Yes, I meant strongest condition; I started off asking what weaker condition you could replace "nuclear" with and edited badly.

Comment: Yes, in a sense, Pandelis.  It might be that every compact operator on Pisier's space is nuclear, in which case not every compact operator on his space would be a commutator of compact operators.  However, nothing is known about non approximable operators on Pisier's space.

Comment: OK, resolving my conjecture seems to be too hard for an MO problem, but what about the second question:  If $X$ is isomorphic to its hyperplanes and to its square, must every finite rank operator on $X$ be a commutator?  We know that the hypotheses imply that every diagonalizable finite rank operator is a commutator.  The bounty also applies to answering this question, but perhaps more attractive is that if you give a simple answer you can prove (although not for the first time) that I am stupid or senile.

Comment: @Mark. The simplest example I see, in $\ell^p({\mathbb N})$, is the commutator of the left and right shifts. It equals the projection on ${\mathbb R}\times\ell^p$, whose trace is $1$, of course.